# How to writte matrice(2d array) into listbox

Tags: asp.net, arrays, listbox

I have tried following code but it writes in vertical way.How can i add 2d array into my listbox

```
 for (int i = 0; i < test.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                ListBox3.Items.Add("-" + test[i, j].ToString());

            }
            ListBox3.Items.Add("\n");
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you from what I understand from your query;

```
string listboxstr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < test.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        listboxstr = "" + test[i, 0].ToString();
        for (int j = 1; j < test.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            listboxstr +="-" + test[i, j].ToString();

        }
        ListBox3.Items.Add(listboxstr);
        ListBox3.Items.Add("\n");
    }

    }
```